# jquery : alternate row colour in table except cell with class to keep background colour

Tags: jquery, css, css-specificity

I am new to jquery. I have this in my code:

```
$("tbody tr:odd ").addClass("alt");
```

with css:

```
tbody tr.alt td {
   background-color: #e6EEEE;
}
```

I have a cell in table with

```
<td class="coloron">
```

Right now, the every other row command is over riding my class="coloron".

How can I maintain my cell unique colour while having every other row colouring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the styles so that your unique color is defined **later** in the stylesheet, like this:

```
tbody tr.alt td {
  background-color: #e6EEEE;
}
tbody tr td.coloron {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

If a row has multiple classes, given the same level of specificity in the style rule, the one defined last in the CSS wins.  [You can see it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/7yStD/).

Comment: @Gordon - welcome :) be sure to accept an answer if it resolves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your `tbody tr.alt td` is more [specific](http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/) than `.coloron` and will override it, instead do something like this:

```
tbody tr.alt td.coloron {
   // your CSS
}
```

Or perhaps this:

```
tbody tr td.coloron {
   // your CSS
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use css `!important`:

```
td.coloron {
    background: #ccc !important;
}
```

Comment: No! This is the wrong way to solve CSS specificity problems, just proves ones lack of understanding of the initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this in your CSS:

.coloron, .coloron.alt { background:red }

Comment: One is a `<td>`, one is a `<tr>` :)

Comment: Can you even combine classes like that?

Comment: @ILMV - Yep, but since they're not on the same element, it doesn't apply here.

Comment: Cheers Nick, was questioning their use in general, you're right the classes belong to two separate elements.